# Vue.js failed to compile error using material design icons iconfont

Tags: vue.js

I am pretty new at vue.js and trying to run a project. when I command 'npm run serve' i got error below:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot' in '(path to project folder)\src\pages'
Here is how i import:

```
<style lang="scss">
@import "~material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons";

</style>
```

I have MaterialIcons-Regular.eot file with path: ....../dist/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot
searched a lot but couldnt find a solution.

I tried reinstall material-design-icons-iconfont but it didn't help and I have no solutions because this is my first experience with vue

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to replace your import with the following

```
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont'
```

Put it in `main.js`

Or you could do easier thing and use https://fonts.google.com/icons